# ¿Cómo pasar valor a input y que funcion on input lo detecte?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

Tengo un input, con una función on input en javascript que envia e valor del input cada vez que cambia de valor, pero le quiero pasar un valor al input con javascript, pero la funcion no detecta que el valor cambio.

```js
    $('#descuento').val(10);

    $('#descuento').on('input', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       let val = $(this).val();
       console.log(val);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="descuento">Descuento:</label>
           <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text iconType">$</span>
               </div>
               <input type="double" class="form-control" disabled id="descuento" value="">
           </div>
    </div>
```

Cualquier ayuda para que la función detecte que cambio el valor, es bienvenida muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El evento `input` solo se activa cuando el cambio es hecho por el usuario.  Si quieres activar el evento programaticamente puedes utilizar `trigger()` asi:

```js
$('#descuento').on('input', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let val = $(this).val();
   console.log(val);
});
$('#descuento').val(10);
$('#descuento').trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="descuento">Descuento:</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text iconType">$</span>
           </div>
           <input type="double" class="form-control" disabled id="descuento" value="">
       </div>
 </div>
```